# Unity3d Perfecting rotation angles after tweening

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interpolation

I've creating a function that rotates 90 degrees with easing.  Almost everything is working perfectly except for perfecting the angles.

This is the code that is necessary for rotating

```
protected bool _isRotating = false;

/// <summary>
/// Rotates the hand around a specific point
/// </summary>
/// <param name="point">The point to rotate around</param>
/// <param name="perspective">
///  The perspective view in which the transform occurs, by default this is Camera.Main
/// </param>
public IEnumerator RotateHand(GameHelper.Axis axis, bool isPositiveDirection, 
                              Vector3 isolatedRotationPoint, float inTime = 1f, 
                              int degrees = GameHelper.RIGHT_ANGLE_DEGREES,
                              Transform perspective = null)
{
    if (_isRotating)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    _isRotating = true;

    var targetPerspective = perspective ?? Camera.main.transform;

    int charge = isPositiveDirection ? 1 : -1;
    int normalizedDegrees = degrees * charge;

    var noralizedAxisVector = this.GetNormalizeHandVector(axis, targetPerspective);;

    var perfectAngles = transform.eulerAngles + (noralizedAxisVector * normalizedDegrees);
    var perfectedAngles = new Vector3(perfectAngles.x, perfectAngles.y, perfectAngles.z);

    float endTime = Time.time + inTime;
    while (Time.time < endTime)
    {
        var delta = normalizedDegrees * (Time.deltaTime / inTime);
        transform.RotateAround(isolatedRotationPoint, noralizedAxisVector, delta);

        Debug.Log(transform.rotation);

        yield return null;
    }


    //Gimbal Lock, correct end values for loss in floating point percision
    transform.eulerAngles = perfectedAngles;
    Debug.Log(transform.rotation);


    _isRotating = false;
}
```

The normalize axis function just returns the normalized transform direction of the primary camera.

My main issue is that after the rotation easing it seems like.

The Y axis actually perfect it's angles correctly, but the z and x seem to be off.  I've tried swapping the x and z values just incase but that didn't seem to work.

I'm new to unity3d, please let me know if there is anything else I can improve with my code as well?

Does anyone know how to correct my algorithm so it will perfect the angles appropriately?

Comment: The `perfectAngles = transform.eulerAngles + ...` will be the point that throws your calc of (you have a typo there btw. `noralizedAxisVector`). This one probably has imprecise float values. Maybe using `Quaternions` for the rotation will give you better results (also there is no gimbal lock with them).

Comment: @GunnarB.  I tried to use quaternions but they have no rotate around function. I could try to use it for perfecting the angles but how would I calculate the ending rotation?